# How to get back accidentally removed kvm module

Tags: centos-7

I accidentally did `modprobe -r kvm` but unable to get  back kvm working.
tried to install it back by `yum install kvm` it installed qemu-system-x86.x86_64 2:2.0.0-1.el7.6.

but still it does not work.

```
[root@centos ~]# lsmod  | grep kvm
kvm                   525409  0
```

libvirtd status :

```
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-11-01 19:27:40 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 24959 (libvirtd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─ 3670 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
           ├─ 3671 /sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
           └─24959 /usr/sbin/libvirtd

Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com dnsmasq[3670]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com dnsmasq-dhcp[3670]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: libvirt version: 1.2.17, package: 13.el7_2.5 (CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>,...tos.org)
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: File /run/media/mukesh/Local Disk SSD/ova/OVA/LabIPA-small/Labipa_2.0_3s-disk1.vmdk matche...dhat.com
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: File /home/mukesh/Downloads/OVA/server2/server2_2.0_5-disk1.vmdk matches vmdk magic, but v...dhat.com
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: File /home/mukesh/Downloads/OVA/server2/server2_2.0_5-disk2.vmdk matches vmdk magic, but v...dhat.com
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: File /home/mukesh/Downloads/OVA/LabIPA-small/Labipa_2.0_3s-disk1.vmdk matches vmdk magic, ...dhat.com
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: File /home/mukesh/Downloads/OVA/IE10.Win7.For.Windows.VMware/IE10_-_Win7-disk1.vmdk matche...dhat.com
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: cannot open path '/home/mukesh/Downloads/LabIPA-small': No such file or directory
Nov 01 19:27:41 centos.chn.com libvirtd[24959]: Failed to autostart storage pool 'LabIPA-small-1': cannot open path '/home/mukesh/Download...irectory
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of `modprobe -r kvm` is `modprobe kvm`, however your `lsmod` output indicates that the kvm kermel module is already loaded.

Your issue is probably from the second output you included, specifically:

```
cannot open path '/home/mukesh/Downloads/LabIPA-small': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Ok i dont know what happened it seems to be working now.thanks